# facebook api fql stream, how to check if its page post or user post?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to check if news feed row is from user or from page. i cant find it anywhere or any field that can tell me if its from user or page. is there anyway i can find that out?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

I'm trying to implement Facebook news feed API. fetching all the users names and pages names that were used on news feed.

if it was already saved in local db, then don't fetch from Facebook, if its not saved, then fetch from Facebook API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to query the [`profile`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/profile) table to get this.

```
SELECT id, type FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #STREAM_QUERY)
```

The `type` field will tell you if the actor is a user, page, event, group or application.

Comment: Thank you. also quick question, stream table does not return cover photo offset, do we have to query that again on user table, to get it?